# Not able to get the data insert into snowflake database, through snowflake kafka connector, however connector is getting started

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect, snowflake-connector

```
Kafka,Zookeeper user@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX config]$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @snowflake-connector.json http://XX.XX.XX.XXX:8083/connectors
{"name":"file-stream-distributed","config":{"connector.class":"com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector","tasks.max":"1","topics":"uat.product.topic","buffer.count.records":"10000","buffer.flush.time":"60","buffer.size.bytes":"5000000","snowflake.url.name":"XXX00000.XX-XXXX-0.snowflakecomputing.com:443","snowflake.user.name":"kafka_connector_user_1","snowflake.private.key":"XXXXX,"snowflake.database.name":"KAFKA_DB","snowflake.schema.name":"KAFKA_SCHEMA","key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter","key.converter.schemas.enable":"true","value.converter":"com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeJsonConverter","value.converter:schemas.enable":"true","value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081","name":"file-stream-distributed"},"tasks":[],"type":"sink"}[Panamax-UAT-Kafka,Zookeeper deploy@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX config]$
Kafka,Zookeeper user@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX config]$
```

Checking for the status of connector: But its giving not found

```
Kafka,Zookeeper user@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX config]$ curl XX.XX.XX.XXX:8083/connectors/file-stream-demo-distributed/tasks
{"error_code":404,"message":"Connector file-stream-demo-distributed not found"}
Kafka,Zookeeper user@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX config]$
```

And the data is not getting inserted into the database

```
logs: /opt/Kafka/kafka/logs/connect.logs: 
[2022-05-29 14:51:22,521] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Joined group at generation 39 with protocol version 2 and got assignment: Assignme        nt{error=0, leader='connect-1-fee23ff6-e61d-4e4c-982d-da2af6272a08', leaderUrl='http://XX.XX.XX.XXX:8083/', offset=4353, connectorIds=[], taskIds=[], revokedConnector        Ids=[], revokedTaskIds=[], delay=0} with rebalance delay: 0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1681)
```

Comment: Can you enable Kafka/JDBC logging as per [this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-ts.html#reporting-issues) and check the logs after?

Comment: Did the R and D, the name was being given wrong as the connector name was file-stream-distributed and not file-stream-demo-distributed. Post this try to execute the details, data is getting pushed but not getting reflected into the database tables, but ts in stage and pipes

Comment: Please edit your question to remove the typo if you're still having issues

Comment: Edited the topic as you guided. Currently I am not able to insert the data but I am able to take the data till stage and pipes. Table is not getting created

Comment: Can you grant Public Schema access to the DB and Schema  

"Grant Kafka_db and Kafka_schema access to Public Schema";

Once done then try to insert the data.

Comment: Well I am not able to have auto table creation, but when given table 2 topic mapping I am able to insert the data. Else I am not able to create auto creation of the table based on topic.

**DATA IS INSERTED WITH BELOW**
snowflake-connector.json : part of the connector
"topics":"uat.invoice.topic",
"snowflake.topic2table.map": "uat.invoice.topic:invoice_table”

**DATA IS NOT GETTING INSERTED WITH BELOW**
snowflake-connector.json : part of the connector
"topics":"uat.invoice.topic",

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a user that has appropriate CREATE TABLE privileges for use in Kafka connector. Suggest you review the documention.

Comment: Yes, the role has appropriate create access for the future tables

Comment: Be sure you have all of the other privileges for the role, e.g. CREATE STAGE, etc.
Also, if you performed the "FUTURE" after you configured the connector, you may need to restart the connector.

Suggest you also provide the config script here

Comment: Thats correct the future is already given, else the new objects will be not able to create and even without restarting we cannot have the new tables coming into affect, so even this was done

Comment: Hard to provide more help without seeing config file, grants, roles, etc.
FYI, we grant the schema owning role to the Kafka user. We have a separate ADMIN role for each database. This reduced number for roles need for VIEWs and tables in different schema within each database.

Comment: Try simple GRANT CREATE TABLE ... TO ROLE used by Kafka Connector.
I suspect expect using FUTURE is not quite what is needed.
We typically use the OWNER ROLE for the Kafka User to simplify our deployment.